# CLI text editor for Linux that supports scrolling bar and stdin reading?

Tags: gui, text-editor, command-line, mouse

Is there a CLI text editor for Linux that supports a scroll bar useable with the mouse and that can read from stdin ?

If not is there at least a simple GUI text editor that support stdin reading ?
I know gvim do but I can't handle its UI.

Comment: What do you mean by “read from stdin”? Any text editor allows the user to type text and issue commands with the keyboard, so I guess that's not what you mean.